# Output order becomes different in nested query, using Firebase 3, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase to store user info, and I have this nested function that fetch the post info, and then using the UID in post to fetch the user info.

**Nested function to fetch post info and then fetch user**

```
func fetchUser(completion: @escaping (User) -> Void) {
    REF_POST.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").observe(.childAdded, with: { (postData) in
        let post = ConvertPost(data: postData.key)

        print(post.uid) >>>>>>UID ordered by timestamp<<<<<<<<

        REF_USER.child(post.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (userData) in

            print(post.uid) >>>>>>UID order becomes different<<<<<<<<

            let user = ConvertUser(data: userData)
            completion(user)
    })

}
```

I have a print(uid) **before** observing the users, the output is ordered by timestamp, which is what I want:

```
PXT6********  
WT7i********    
WT7i********    
PXT6********
```

And a print(uid) **inside** observing users, the output order is different:

```
WT7i********    
WT7i********    
PXT6********    
PXT6********
```

so my question is **why the order becomes different**?
I'm calling the method in ViewDidLoad()
Is it something to do with the closure block?

#### Question Update

After some testing, I found that the output will always **group the same uid together**, something like A,A,B,B,C,C.  Please help  me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code below:

```
func observeUsers(uid: String, completion:  @escaping (User) -> Void) {
    print(uid)
    REF_USERS.keepSynced(true) // <-- this will make sure your code will update with fresh data
    REF_USERS.child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print(uid)

        let user = ConvertUser(data: snapshot.value)
        completion(user)
        }
    })
}
```

Either use that code, or disable data persistance in your appDelegate. More information:[Firebase : What is the difference between setPersistenceEnabled and keepSynced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190234/firebase-what-is-the-difference-between-setpersistenceenabled-and-keepsynced) and in the docs of Firebase ofcourse.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just tried your code by adding keepSynced(true) and the print output inside the block now becomes  
PXT6********   
PXT6********   WT7i********   
WT7i********

Comment: Whats the order in Firebase?

Comment: in Firebase PXT6***** comes before WT7i******, but I don't think that's the problem....  the uid I pass in is in a certain order, and I want the output(which is the snapshot) to be in the same order.