# Why are we forced to use keepSynced with firebase database?

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am using react native with Firebase Realtime Database. Testing a simple chat app and I am fetching the chats like so:

```
 this.friendChatRef = this.db.ref('messages/' + this.chat_id + '/' + this.friend_id)

 const friendChatRef = this.friendChatRef.limitToLast(9)

 const fcrp = friendChatRef.once('value')
```

The goal is to always get the last 9 messages from the conversation when the component/view mounts.

The problem is that It will fetch 9 chats but they are not the latest in any way. I can add 10+ new messages but they will never be fetched until I add this:

```
 friendChatRef.keepSynced(true)
```

Then every time I access the chat it will fetch the latest 9 messages.

Why do we have to use keepSynched? I thought persistence is just for the offline data caching but it always checks if the cached data is outdated or not every time you create a ref and fetch the data?

Is there any way to keep the persistence and not use keepSynched to get the latest data?

Comment: "The problem is that It will fetch 9 chats but they are not the latest in any way." The code you shared doesn't read any data yet. If you have a problem, always show the minimal code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added extra code, but this is the db ref to get the latest 9 messages from that ref. The key is that without having `keepSynced` simply not going to fetch them as they should and having it to `true`, works as expected

Comment: You're using `once()`, which doesn't work well together with disk persistence. See my detailed answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190234/firebase-what-is-the-difference-between-setpersistenceenabled-and-keepsynced/40193807#40193807 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent/34487195#34487195. Essentially: you'll either have to use `on()` or `keepSynced` (which essentially keeps an empty `on()` listener on the location) for this to work..

Comment: Its a shame I can not fetch from the cache and then check the db ref once for the new data and have to use `keepSynced` instead as for me to have a listener always is not a good option here

Comment: Calling `keepSynced(true)` adds an empty listener to the location.